# Unknown PHP artisan tinker output

Tags: php, laravel-5

I have entered these following lines in cmder:

```
$ php artisan make:migration create_articles_table --table="articles"
$ php artisan migrate
$ php artisan make:model Articles
```

Then I use php tinker:

```
$ php artisan tinker
>>>$article = new App\Articles
```

but I got this output:

```
=> <App\Articles #000000001bc562f60000000040231bd3> {}
```

Can anyone explain this output?

Comment: Did you specify any fields in crate_articles_table migration script

Comment: Yes, $table->text('body');

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I have ask the same question to laracast forum and got the solution.
https://laracasts.com/discuss/channels/general-discussion/unknown-artisan-tinker-output

According to that link. This output is not a problem.

```
=> <App\Articles #000000001bc562f60000000040231bd3> {}
```

It's just fine and you can go for your next step.
For example, in your case you can go with this.

```
>>>$article->foo = "bar";
>>>$article->save();
```

Now if you want to select your article, try this.

```
>>>App\Article::first();
```

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes.

Comment: Great dude.
I'll try to re write my answer.